# Google Plus API for iOS: Share function - Crash app when touching "Public" in the native dialog share?

Tags: ios, google-plus

I used Google Plus API in my application for sharing content.
I used these lines for showing the native share dialog in my application:

```
id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];

[shareBuilder setPrefillText:MY_TEXT];

[shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:MY_URL];

[shareBuilder open];
```

Dialog was shown successfully. When I touched "Public" for changing privacy, crash app immediately.

I am using XCode 5 and my iphone is iOS 5.0. XCode shows log:

```
Uncaught exception: 

-[NSCache setObject:forKey:cost:]: attempt to insert nil value (key:acl_public_com.google.GPPCommonSharedResources)
Stack trace: (

0   CoreFoundation                      0x33e6f8d7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x340bf1e5 objc_exception_throw + 32

2   CoreFoundation                      0x33e00cf5 +[NSObject copyWithZone:] + 0

3   CoreFoundation                      0x33e024a1 -[NSCache setObject:forKey:] + 44

4   MyApp                                0x002f86e5 +[UIImage(GPPAdditions) gpp_setCachedImage:forKey:] 

5   MyAPP                                0x002f8535 +[UIImage(GPPAdditions) gpp_imageNamed:bundle:] + 220

6   MyApp                                0x002f85df +[UIImage(GPPAdditions) gpp_imageNamed:tint:bundle:] + 13
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hey, please help me if you have you found the solution. I am getting same crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem is rather simple. I spent 3 days working on this though. While playing with google's sample app I discovered that the bundle name was missing in the custom iOS Target Properties of my app. Just add a simple line with `${PRODUCT_NAME}` and everything should be fine :D